# Error after using @Module annotation of Dagger on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-2

I have been getting this error after using @Module annotion of dagger on my sample kotlin project.

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

The error is thrown during compile time on kaptDebugKotlin task of gradle. Anyone else getting similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that issue is gone after updating the Dagger version I have been using. Credit to [this](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/google/dagger/2845) post (referring to [google/dagger#2845](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2845) and [google/dagger#2511](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2511)), I was able to get rid of the error. I have been using version 2.28, and after updating to 2.34 the error is gone.